# Trying to write a method in ruby that only takes items with integers and converts to an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to convert the following string into an array with a list of integers.

```
"---\n- ''\n- '1060500964'\n- '1060500869'\n- '106050099..."
```

The array should look like: `[1060500964, 1060500869, 106050099]`

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/). You can parse it with the standard YAML library (since ruby 1.9.2):

```
require 'yaml'
YAML.load("---\n- ''\n- '1060500964'\n- '1060500869'\n- '106050099'")
 .reject(&:empty?)
 .map(&:to_i)
=> [1060500964, 1060500869, 106050099]
```

Comment: This is the right way to do this. The string is YAML, so treat it as YAML. But YAML isn't in core, it's in [the Standard Library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/index.html), otherwise it wouldn't have to be required.

Comment: I didn't even know it was yaml! I'll definitely recognize it next time I see it, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
numbers = []
string_array = "---\n- ''\n- '1060500964'\n- '1060500869'\n- '106050099...".delete("'").split
string_array.each do |item|
    num = item.to_i
    numbers << num if num!=0
end
```